generating header file in presence of not infinitely circular dependencies
Hum, it's a little difficult to explain, especially in the title...
Let's say I have the following files: main.cpp, domain.cpp, domain.hpp, generated.hpp and generator.cpp. domain.cpp includes domain.hpp, which in turn includes generated.hpp. I want to build two executables:

generator, consisting of generator.cpp and domain.cpp
main, consisting of main.cpp and domain.cpp

Here's the twist. Initially, generated.hpp is empty. Before building main, I want to build generator (if needed), and always run it before building main. generator calculates stuff related to domains.cpp, and rewrites generated.hpp - but only if its content would be different. Thus, running generator for the first time will rewrite the empty generated.hpp; running it again immediately afterwards will not touch generated.hpp; and running generator after making changes to the domain.?pp files may or may not rewrite generated.hpp.
Thus, there is a cycle because generator depends on its output, but it will be traversed only once.
Moreover, generator has to run before ninja/make/whatever starts examining the dependencies of main.
Can it be achieved in plain cmake, without playing tricks with scripts?
It would be nice if the generated generated.hpp goes in the build area.
The files are in C++17, thus solutions that involve __has_include are acceptable. But I doubt it can help.
PS In case you wonder about the context, it's for my YOMM2 open multi-methods library. generator calculates offsets in v-tables, and writes them as constexpr offsets. If present, they are used to speed up method dispatch.

Can it be achieved in plain cmake sounds like it. Start writing it and check out. Ask a question when you have a specific problem you are trying to solve. Generating source files is quite common in C world. Use add_custom_command. What is unclera to me is how generator depends on the file it generates. For me there are two generators - first one generated from an empty file, and second one compiled from the generated file - and dependency is a tree.

@KamilCuk In YOMM2, main has to call update to generate dispatch tables and offsets in v-tables used during method dispatch. The offsets are stored in variables, which I want to eliminate. The idea is to build a generator program that contains exactly the same methods, methods definitions and classes, calculates the offsets, and writes a header containing the offsets as constexprs,to be included by the "domains" files. I tried to describe a specific problem and I did spend hours with add_custom_commands, and experimenting with BYPRODUCTS.

I did spend hours with  Please consider posting your tries.  Including any non-working code in a question is much better than no code at all. At best, create a full [MCVE] with all source codes to reproduce the issue. Right now, while I can write an answer, there is no way for me to test it, so it will be only theoretical. experimenting with BYPRODUCTS And theoretically, it doesn't look to me you need byproducts. generate generates one file generated.hpp . I also do not like the idea of mixing generated with non-generated code. I would start with always empty generated.hpp.

CMakeLists.txt
initially/generated.hpp   # "Initially, generated.hpp is empty."
src/ main.cpp domain.cpp domain.hpp generator.cpp

Then:
# running generator for the first time will rewrite the empty generated.hpp
add_executable(generator_firsttime src/generator.cpp)
target_include_directories(generator_firsttime PRIVATE initially)
add_custom_command(
   OUTPUT ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/firsttime/generated.hpp
   COMMAND generator_firsttime 
      -o ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/firsttime/generated.hpp
   DEPENDS generator_firsttime src/domains.cpp
)
add_custom_target(generated_firsttime_generated_hpp DEPENDS ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/firsttime/generated.hpp)

add_executable(generator_secondtime src/generator.cpp)
target_include_directories(generator_secondtime PRIVATE ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/firsttime)
add_dependencies(generator_secondtime generated_firsttime_generated_hpp)
add_custom_command(
   OUTPUT ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/secondtime/generated.hpp
   COMMAND generator_secondtime 
      -o ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/secondtime/generated.hpp
   DEPENDS generator_secondtime src/domains.cpp
)
add_custom_target(generated_firsttime_generated_hpp DEPENDS ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/secondtime/generated.hpp)

# for ease of use
add_library(generated_hpp INTERFACE)
add_dependency(firsttime_generated_hpp generated_firsttime_generated_hpp)
target_include_directories(generated_hpp INTERFACE {CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/secondtime)

# not compile your program
add_executable(main src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE generated_hpp)


After a couple of fixes, this worked. Thanks a lot, you saved me a lot of time. Accepting the answer, perhaps you want to amend your post with my changes.
